# convert ternary operator to if else in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

I've created posts table and display on interface post table. so I want to display the owner of the post by using thier name. the first step is I use ternary operator but I want to change to if else statement. But If try second way will get the error:

> syntax error, unexpected '{' (View:.

how the correct way If I want to use the second way.

First way

```
<td>{{ isset($post->user) ? $post->user->name : '' }}</td>
```

Second Way

```
<td>
    @if(isset($post->user)
    {
        $post->user->name;
    }
    else
    {
        '';
    });
    @endif
</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

`@if (...)` gets compiled to `<?php if (...): ?>`. So you are no longer in the context of PHP tags between the Blade directives.

You can do this simply by using Blade though:

```
@if(isset($post->user))
    {{ $post->user->name }}
@endif

--- which is basically:

<?php if (isset($post->user)): ?>
    <?php echo e($post->user->name); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

There is no need for the `else` branch here with your example.

Alternative:

```
{{ $post->user->name ?? '' }}
```